# Is it possible to create few service proxies with the same method names?

Tags: service, proxy, vert.x

1st service proxy:

package com.test.resource.handler;

@ProxyGen
public interface ResourceContract {

```
static ResourceContract create(Vertx vertx, Logger logger) {
    return new ResourceHandler(vertx, logger);
}

static ResourceContract createProxy(Vertx vertx, String address) {
    return new ResourceContractVertxEBProxy(vertx, address);
}

void create();

void read();

void update();

void delete();
```

}

and 2nd service proxy:

package com.test.agent.handler;

@ProxyGen
public interface AgentContract {

```
static AgentContract create(Vertx vertx, Logger logger) {
    return new AgentHandler(vertx, logger);
}

static AgentContract createProxy(Vertx vertx, String address) {
    return new AgentContractVertxEBProxy(vertx, address);
}

void create();

void read();

void update();

void delete();
```

}

During building receive error: `Overloaded methods are not allowed in ProxyGen interfaces`

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible as far as I know, because the method names are turned into event bus addresses: create, read, update, delete. But haven't worked with services for quite a while.

EDIT: Just read the docs. Methods are mapped to actions and services have an address. Maybe the static create methods are causing the issue here.

Comment: what i see at generated code


`DeliveryOptions _deliveryOptions = (_options != null) ? new DeliveryOptions(_options) : new DeliveryOptions();
    _deliveryOptions.addHeader("action", "read");
    _deliveryOptions.getHeaders().set("action", "read");
    _vertx.eventBus().send(_address, _json, _deliveryOptions);`

Comment: `_address` is unique value crose other service proxies